# All data in one CSV column even though i split them up with a dataframe or setting seperate columns manually

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, csv

No matter what I try, if I try to convert a df into a csv or do it manually by the csv library.

I have looked for some solutions on StackOverflow and YouTube but did not find anything-

```
#the variables are arrays with values in them 

    f = pd.DataFrame(
            {"Land" : country_names,
            "Haupstadt" : capitals,
            "Population" : populations,
             "Flächer in Km²" : areas})
    df.head(10)

    df.to_csv("./länder.csv")

    # https://imgur.com/a/nAiYlLb this is the output of the DataFrame(not the csv)
```

I expect the output of a csv file with 4 columns, but the actual output is everything squeezed in one column.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtiKO.jpg (this is the csv file)

Comment: "csv"s in some languages are actually separated by semi-colons, I mention this because it looks like the wrong text encoding was used at some point. In addition I see some German text. Have you tried opening the csv in a text editor? Do you know what encoding was used to save it?

Comment: Can you try opening it up in Google sheets by importing as CSV or properly setting up separator as "," in your current tool you are using to view CSV.

Comment: I am sorry I do not know how to reply to someone separately so i will try it by just writing 2 comments

Comment: I think I used UTF-8 and I when i opened it in a notepad and it showed looked like this https://imgur.com/a/WaMX6SH

Comment: I tried it in Google sheets and it worked perfectly but I could not find how to set the seperator in Excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`csv` means comma separated values.

pandas does exactly what you're telling him to: it gives you a file with your values separated by commas.

Excel by default uses a `;` separator. If you don't want to change your settings in Excel, you have two possibilities:

Specify the separator when you save your file with pandas:

```
df.to_csv("your_file.csv", sep = ";")
```

Or save your file to an Excel file (pandas allows it):

```
 df.to_excel("your_file.xlsx")
```